# Problem with "OverBar"

Tags: continued-fractions

In my equation, I would like to add a bar to the second fraction, but the "`OverBar`" does not work.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me what the problem is.

[image]

This is my code:

```
HoldForm[ 
TraditionalForm[
D[Subscript[OverTilde[u], i], Subscript[x, k]]] TraditionalForm[
D[Subscript[OverTilde[u], j], Subscript[x, k]]] - (OverBar[
TraditionalForm[
  D[Subscript[OverTilde[u], i], Subscript[x, k]]] TraditionalForm[
  D[Subscript[OverTilde[u], j], Subscript[x, k]]]])] here

IndexedExpression[i, j, k]
```

Comment: Works fine with v14.0. Note that only one `TraditionalForm` is needed. `HoldForm[TraditionalForm@(D[Subscript[OverTilde[u], i], Subscript[x, k]]  D[Subscript[OverTilde[u], j], Subscript[x, k]] - (OverBar[D[Subscript[OverTilde[u], i], Subscript[x, k]]  D[Subscript[OverTilde[u], j], Subscript[x, k]]]))]`

Answer (score 2):

Works fine in V 13.1 (see below):

[image]

Comment: yes, but when I add next line it faces the problem.
    Table[IndexedExpression[a, b, c], {a, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 3}, {c, 1, 3}]